# How long does it take to receive the Census badge for the Developer Survey?

Tags: support, survey, survey-2017

I finished the survey about an hour ago, but the promised badge hasn't arrived yet.

What's the matter? How long do I have to wait before receiving this badge?

Comment: You aren't pursuing a [patience] badge, I see.

Comment: This is correct 

Comment: @Mafii or paying attention for that matter, it's stated right at the end of the survey.

Comment: I have received it already

Comment: @VivekMishra I have recieved mine today, too

Answer (score 35):

As it was stated in the survey itself, the badge will be awarded in batches at the end of January.

Update: They have [started to be manually rewarded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341924/4074148) on Tuesday 31st January 2017.

Comment: Whoops, didnt pay enough attention then. Thanks

Comment: @Mafii So your survey anwers aren't usable due to that lack of attention?

Comment: @Tom incorrect, once the questions were all asked I lost focus ;)

Comment: "A batch of badges". That needs to be added to the list of [collective nouns](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/08/collective-nouns/).

Comment: *One of the batches* was awarded that day. There was another batch awarded earlier, and there may follow additional batches.

Comment: However... I still don't have the badge after finishing the survey.... Is there something I did wrongly