# Are silver "census" badges still awarded?

Tags: support, badges

I read some info [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge/341924#341924), but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census) makes me think that no more badges will be awarded. Am I wrong? Why?
In [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341475/how-long-does-it-take-to-receive-the-census-badge-for-the-developer-survey) question, they explained what used to happen before January 31st. How does it work, now?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, he wrote before they were awarded on January 31st. Now that time has expired.

Comment: Does that mean, you won't get the silver census badge if you complete the Developer Survey in February?

Comment: @Jaco, that's what I'm asking to know.

Comment: That answer is wrong, *one of the batches* was awarded that day. There was another batch awarded earlier, and there may follow additional batches.

Comment: There is no automatic process. There is an excel sheet and there is Jon Ericson. Jon comes without an SLA ... but let's be glad he takes this on whenever he has some time left ....

Comment: They've obviously just kept the survey open much longer than they intended to, probably because participation has been down. There's no reason to assume you won't get a badge. And if you don't, will it prevent you from taking the survey?

Comment: Actually, I knewn about the badge onfly after completing the survey, so I have already done it. I was just curious to know.

Comment: On a side note, couldn't the whole thing be automated (the spreadsheet plus quickly writing a program to do it will take around a couple of hours, probably far less time it'll take to go through the entire list).

Comment: @cybermonkey they probably want to do it manually this year since it's a new badge. Also, the inputs from this free text field need to be cleaned.

Comment: As the duplicate says, they are being awarded in batches *starting* January 31st