# When is Census badge awarded for people completed the survey in February?

Tags: support, badges, survey

I completed the Developer Survey in February and I couldn't find any information on when the badge will be awarded in such case.

The only thing I could find is outdated information, from back when the survey was meant to be closed at the end of January and it said the badge will be awarded at Tuesday 31st January 2017.

I saw similar question on the topic here, but it didn't answer my question regarding people who completed the survey in February:
[How long does it take to receive the Census badge for the Developer Survey?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341475/how-long-does-it-take-to-receive-the-census-badge-for-the-developer-survey)

My question is different from the one above, because I asked how long it takes, now that the situation has changed and the survey was extended to February, not like the user in the above link, that asked about the original time it took to award the badge. In this new case someone might say no badge will be awarded at all (but I still hope a badge will be awarded).

People who think this is a duplicate, please leave a comment explaining why.
I see more than one person thinks so, so I might be missing something.
But I did do my research, and that question (+ good answer, even though user who already received his badge didn't mark it as accepted) does not help my case.

And in another note, it is kind of funny my question is marked duplicate of a question I provided a link to from the very beginning.

Comment: Approximately 6-8 weeks

Comment: @TinyGiant, is that official or a rumor?

Comment: It's kind of a cross between [official and rumor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/288751), everything 'round these parts happens in 6 to 8 somethings.

Comment: These badges are being *manually awarded*. There is no exact answer, other than "whenever Jon Ericson or someone else who takes over gets a [round tuit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round_tuit)".

Comment: Does it really matter? It's a badge. There was some text describing when you'd get the badge, for which you needed to put in your Profile link. It was an "around the end of" type thing. It'll come, and if it doesn't come it doesn't matter does it?

Comment: @CodyGray, since there was a date for people who completed the survey in January, I expected there to be one for February too.

Comment: @BillWoodger, yes, there was a text. It said end of January, but it doesn't apply to me, since I completed in February. And it matters a little, otherwise I wouldn't supply the link to my profile in order to get the badge in the first place. So I want it come, and if it's not going to. I'd like to know.

Comment: Yeah, the survey has obviously been left running for longer than they ever intended for it to run. Certainly longer than it has run in the past. Probably due to low participation; maybe to their failure to get the word out via Meta, maybe because of serious design & UX problems with the survey. Anyway, the date given in the survey for January was approximate, reflecting when they expected the survey to close, and taking into account the fact that someone is *manually* awarding these badges, as I already pointed out. The same applies for February, just…later. It'll come.

Comment: Duplicate status means this question has the same answer. I explained *why* it is the same answer in my initial comment: someone is awarding the badges manually, so they will come, but there is no guaranteed time. No one can give you a precise time until they actually *do* it, and then they can post an answer that says, "yeah, I done done it." I don't see a compelling reason for the question to remain open until that time, do you? The point is to get an answer—you've gotten your answer. There's nothing "funny" about a question being closed as a duplicate. Don't take offense to it.

Comment: @CodyGray, thanks for elaborating. It is appreciated.