# Census badge link 404s

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Just got [A Shiny Silver Census Badge!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge)

[image]

See?

...but if I [click that link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census?userid=811), things get sad:

[image: four-oh-four]

Also, the Census badge doesn't appear on https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges

(except for the sidebar, where it shows a whole bunch of 'em being awarded... All with broken links.)

Comment: Looks like the badge description is missing as well (hence the empty parentheses).

Comment: [You only got one badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge#comment430392_341214)?

Comment: Right? Either I failed to convince anyone to use my profile link, or some dev put in a check to prevent duplicate awards. That'll teach me to reveal my nefarious plans ahead of time...

Comment: I came here to report this, but I saw you had the same idea earlier than me. (I have to say it's 11:10 PM my time; I am not that responsive at this moment of the day.)

Comment: I see it in the badges in the site badge listing, but not on my profile. No worries, I don't need need one anyway!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This turned out to be my fault. There was a big old warning on the page for awarding the badge that said:

> WARNING: The Census badge is currently DISABLED in this site. If you continue, the badges will be awarded anyway AND will be visible in the user profiles!

Once I flipped the site setting, the Census badge page came into being.

Reading *is* fundamental. Also, next time I will try to remember to test on my own profile before doing 800+ at one go.

Comment: Oddly the [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) lacks a description :P

Comment: That should be fixed after the next build, @xQbert

Comment: If only I could get away with that!

Comment: @xQbert - description is now there.

Comment: @Oded the description of "Census" uses "their", instead of "your" like the others, e.g. "Promoter".

Comment: Could this have something to do with [the `badges/name` API endpoint being broken (again)](http://stackapps.com/questions/7064/bug-with-badges-name-endpoint)?

Comment: @Stijn - yeah. Fixed now.

Comment: @Oded So in the future, instead of [posting on Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289872/what-broke-the-api-on-jan-13-and-jan-14-2017) or [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/questions/7064/bug-with-badges-name-endpoint), and [sending a contact request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), what should we do if the API endpoint (or others) break again, should I just ping Shog9? It's kind of disconcerting to have this broken *for a whole week* before anyone did anything or gave any updates until Shog9 posts a question here...not trying to be rude, *but*, what the heck?

Comment: Well, you reminded me that I hadn't added the stackapps feed to my watchlist, @EBrown. Not sayin' that's gonna help anything, but there's at least a slightly better chance someone will see it.

Comment: @Shog9 Well I was just a little discontented with the fact that I posted on Stack Apps months ago, it got fixed (silently), then it breaks again, I update the Stack Apps post and post on Meta.SE, put in a contact request, and nothing. At first I didn't realize the endpoint was broke again, but when I did was when I submitted the contact request (I think 2 days ago) and got nothing back, again. Like I said, I don't mean to be rude but it was a bit upsetting to have this broken for a whole week with no info at all. Even [Tim Stone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289982/) had a problem.

Comment: @EBrown: Fundamentally the problem is that the API can remain broken without us really paying attention to it. I appreciate your report since it prompted us to rebuild the API. (That was the immediate problem this time around.) But we shouldn't really be relying on user reports for this sort of thing. We need to start [treating our products as a platform](https://plus.google.com/+RipRowan/posts/eVeouesvaVX). We don't treat our API as mission critical. There's good reasons for that, but it's going to hurt us if we don't sort it out eventually. (Summary: sorry about that. We can do better.)

Comment: @JonEricson I agree that you shouldn't rely on user reports, but if a user *does* report it a follow-up would be great. Instead we get ignored and the problem persists. It's not particularly hard to take a report like this (with clear conditions to replicate the issue) and follow up on testing it. I was able to test all conditions to create this within moments. If you get a report, and you start working on it, an excellent response is 'We're in the process of fixing this.' Don't leave us hanging, *please*.

Comment: @EBrown: I get the frustration. I don't mean to dismiss your point. However the problem from our side is that we get tons of user reports via all sorts of paths. Most of them are the sorts of things we can sit on for the proverbial 6-8 weeks. But if there's something seriously broken that prevents you from doing your job, that's not gonna work. In that case pinging an employee (especially a CM) is probably a good idea. As far as I know, none of us had seen the reports until today. (Shog's comment was getting at that aspect of the problem. We need to look at all the places.)

Comment: @JonEricson I get it, I suppose it's different if you get dozens, hundreds or thousands of reports a day. (Not sure what your scale is, but it's definitely got to be significantly larger than mine.) I'm glad you were able to clear that up, could you (or another CM) answer my original [report on Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/questions/7064/bug-with-badges-name-endpoint) so I have someone to ping easier *if* it happens again? At the very least it'll help prevent me from searching too hard if *this* particular API problem happens again.

Comment: @EBrown: No problem. It'll also help us remember what we did to fix the problem next time it comes up.

Comment: In the interest of disclosure, I saw the meta report about the broken route late at night earlier this week. I made a mental note to follow up, but also sort of assumed it was probably related to SQL timeouts or something similar that we're waiting on infrastructure updates to fix up, so I didn't retain the "go back and look at that" thought very well. :/

Comment: As far as escalating reports goes, my email's always open (address is in my profile). With the caveat that it's not a "make a dev drop everything and take care of my pet issue" hotline. If it's something trivial or low priority that would be just fine on meta for a while, I'm unlikely to mince words about that.

Comment: @AdamLear Just saw this, that's much appreciated. :) I use the API nightly and do ~2000 calls against each night, I *tend* to notice these things pretty quickly, though sometimes I have the same memory lapses as you described. :)