# Is the Developer Survey really confidential and anonymous?

Tags: discussion, survey-2019

The reason I'm asking is, can employers looking for a developer get personal information about them from the Developer Survey, specifically current salary, if I give it?  To date, this has been my only reservation from filling out the survey as I want to help and promote Stack Overflow anyway I can.

I know that many companies say employee survey's are anonymous, but then the people that voice negative opinions seem to get let go, and I'm not implying this of Stack Overflow, just stating something I've seen at two companies I worked for.  Is it just because that speaks of a bad attitude and poor performance at work or the fact that it wasn't anonymous to begin with?

Like I said, I believe I know of cases at companies where it wasn't anonymous, but management said it was. I also found these two articles on the subject: [The Truth about Employee Engagement Surveys](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/truth-employee-engagement-surveys-other-corporate-bullsht-liz-ryan) and [Employee Engagement Surveys, why do workers distrust them?](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/hr-topics/employee-relations/pages/employee-engagement-surveys.aspx)

So getting back to my original question and adding a more generalized item, is the 2019 Stack Overflow Survey anonymous in the sense that no one, including Stack Overflow or a third party would be able to link my responses back to my profile?

Comment: Stack Overflow is pretty honest when it says it's not sharing your data.  Now, there is the potential of someone subconsciously and loudly voicing their displeasure with their job and there just so happens to be a survey running by Stack Overflow, which could lead to one believing that SO leaked their data...

Comment: Note that if you take the survey on, say, your company's network or VPN, they could theoretically intercept the fact that you're taking the survey. SO and Quantics use HTTPS, which should help mitigate MITM attacks, but if you're being paranoid, might as well go whole-hog :).

Comment: No, I wouldn't do that while at work or using their resources.  I'll do it from home, but thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'm actually somewhat curious: given that you seem inclined to doubt (with fair reason) that companies are telling the truth when they say surveys are anonymous, and given that SO already says that individual survey responses won't be released outside the company but you evidently don't trust that, what sort of a response did you imagine this question getting to convince you otherwise? (Sorry if this sounds accusatory, I don't mean it that way, I'm just honestly wondering what it was you were looking for when you asked this.)

Comment: Actually it is a very good question and no accusation is taken.  I had an unspoken presupposition that if SO had a policy regarding this it would be a truthful one.  SO appears to be committed to honesty and integrity.  This was based on my experiences on SO over the years and it didn't seem that SO would have the same strong motive in deception that a company might towards employees.  Not to imply that all companies do.  So that in itself is still subjective in retrospect, but it's consistent in the fact I accepted the answer at face value and I didn't stop to think how that appeared.

Comment: SO has a base of millions of developers, not a few thousand or tens of thousands of employees. In a sense, the developers are also customers for SO, so it didn't seem reasonable that they would risk that relationship by not being up front on policies like this.  There was a java forum that I used to use, but it developed a bad reputation for not being timely and consistent in getting answers to questions. It's not around in the same format anymore and I don't think the number of people using it are anywhere near what they used to be.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Only SO employees can (potentially) link your responses to your account. Third parties do not get access to any information that might identify you. This is mentioned at the beginning of this year's survey.

The Census badge, when first introduced in 2017, required you to add your profile link at the end of the survey. In response to concerns about anonymity, [Tim Post wrote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge#comment430378_341214):

> Yes, it's totally anonymized. It's nice of people to provide a link so we can get a better picture of their professional world, but that data is only used internally (with our thanks to you) or in aggregate form as we release results.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll take the survey now.  Thanks!

Comment: One small correction. We no longer ask users to provide a link to their profile; we did that in past years.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know and yes I assumed that things were probably different somewhat before, so I qualified it with the current survey year.

Comment: Aside from "it's totally anonymized" and "data is only used internally" most of this is outdated.

Comment: I'm taking the survey right now so I didn't know it no longer asks for your profile link. @AnitaTaylor would you please post an up-to-date answer?

Comment: @TravisJ I've reworded the answer a bit, but I think an official answer would still be better.