# Can I see my responses to previous Stack Overflow developer surveys?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, survey

Just took the [Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/dev-survey/start?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2020), and suddenly I realised one thing.

I feel it would be nice to revisit how our

- Views,
- Opinions and
- Practices

have changed in all these years; to sort of [take a stroll down memory lane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C37lS.jpg).

It would be interesting to see what all has changed, and what [has remained timeless](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFEMO.jpg).
So, is it already possible? Or if not, could it be implemented?

And of course, can we edit our survey responses after bashing that <kbd>Submit</kbd>?
I would assume no, since that would be devious :-)

Comment: You mean you want to see your own answers to the question from previous years? Or do you want to see the general outcome of older surveys?

Comment: @BDL I mean to see my _own_ responses, yes.

Comment: That's hopefully impossible. The answers to the survey are not linked to your account. Would be a huge privacy issue otherwise.

Comment: @BDL Oh. Then how does it track who all have given responses? Anyway, I do not mean they have to store it. I just want a way to maybe download it?

Comment: There is no tracking who gave response except for the badge. You don't even need an SO account to take the survey. Download still means that SO would have some information about who gave which answer which they shouldn't have. The survey is (hopefully) completely anonymous.

Comment: Related: [Is the Developer Survey really confidential and anonymous?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379429/is-the-developer-survey-really-confidential-and-anonymous)

Comment: "There is no tracking who gave response except for the badge." @BDL do you mean if I decline to accept the badge, I wouldn't be marked as an answerer? About the download, the data _is_ going to Stack Overflow's servers. So how is no data stored about the user? A download option could surely be implemented without ensuing loss of privacy.

Comment: Finally found the link explaining what SO stores and how awarding the census badge works: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361613/unlink-profile-from-2018-developer-survey. As I said, the data you enter in the survey is not linked to your account. And yes, if you refuse to take the badge, noone knows that you took the survey. Given that some of the answers in the survey are very sensitive (homosexuality is a death punishable crime in some countries), I think its a very good idea to never store a link between profile and answers.

Comment: @JaideepShekhar They might know *that* you took the survey, but there shouldn't be any way to link your account to the specific answers you gave.

Comment: @Alexei I am not sure the change in title is appropriate. I do not mean "review" as in editing, I mean simply being able to access it.